# Update from iOS 6 to 7, but not to iOS 8?

Tags: ios, software-update

So...I'm still on iOS 6.1. I know, I know, pretty much nobody has iOS 6 now if they can help it. 
Well, I've recently freed up enough space on my iphone 5 to update to iOS 7, but I don't want the iOS 8, and I can't seem to get past that on the software update. Is there anyway I can get the 7 without having to get the 8 at all? Someone once suggested force update by computer, but I'm not sure how that works. Does anyone know, or am I stuck with iOS 6?

Answer (score 6):

As I had mentioned in my comment, Apple is no longer signing iOS 7 which means you can either update to iOS 8 or stay on iOS 6. Usually after an iOS update release, the previous iOS version is supported for a little while and then the signing stops. Right now, Apple signs iOS 8.1.

If you want to know what firmwares are being signed by Apple, there is a neat little website which is updated with the information - http://api.ineal.me/tss/status

Answer (score 0):

As Jash said, Apple is not signing iOS 7 updates anymore. The only articles I found discussing upgrading to 8 and then downgrading were dated around the 25th of September, and one of them even says at the top that as of September 29, Apple had stopped signing iOS 7 updates, so it was no longer possible to downgrade.

Comment: I see, thanks Jash and Tubedogg :) in that case, would you recommend staying at iOS 6 or upgrading? What do you think of the new iOS?

Comment: With an iPhone 5 I would definitely upgrade. There's really no reason not to. Performance-wise your device is recent enough it shouldn't take that much of a hit.